# SSRS Report Server 2019 prompting for username and password

Tags: authentication, reporting-services, reporting

I have installed SQL server 2019 reporting services, created my data sources and reports. Data sources are using SQL server authentication.
I have set the service account to Network Service and even a domain account.
Report Server is running in Native mode.
Executing account is also a domain account.
When I connect to a report using the Report web url, I get windows prompt from windows credentials.
I get the prompt with both localhost and the FQDN

How do I avoid the prompt? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding trusted sites in the web browser settings.

   Go to Tools - Internet Options - Security - Local Intranet - Sites.
2. Have you tried to use other browser such as Chrome for a test?

   Right click and run as administrator to open the url to see if it will still ask for credentials.
3. Remove RSWindowsNegotiate from the RSReportServer.config file and verify that only RSWindowsNTLM is specified.

   Restart SSRS and access the url.

If you use the fully qualified domain name in the url you should not be prompted for credentials.

https://yourservername/Reports/browse

vs

https://yourservername.yourdomain.com/Reports/browse

Also, just in case you're not using a CNAME for the server I highly recommend it. e.g. `reports` instead of `yourservername`

Then `reports` just redirects to the `yourservername`. This helps if you want to upgrade to a new server as well as looks better in the url.